# Функция определения четности(побитовые операции)

Tags: python-3.x

Как можно реализовать функцию определения четности используя только побитовые операторы, кроме & и  >>  ?

```
def solve(x):
    if x % 2 ==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
def solve(x):
    y = x >> 1
    if x == (y << 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def solve(x):
    if x ^ (x | 1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```